# What are the tradeoffs of passing an imported object from parent to children as props vs importing that object in those children?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I have a helper object called TimeHelper (for time-related things). I need to do a lot with dates and times from a top-level parent component and in several of its children components.

I'm wondering what the tradeoffs would be for importing TimeHelper a single time in the top-level parent, then passing it as props to the children VS. importing TimeHelper in every component that needs it?

Edit: to answer Nicholas' questions below:

Is this object ever going to change?
Might get more methods added to it in the future, but won't be mutated after importing.

Do any of its properties come from the state or props of one of your components?
Nope. Stand-alone Object with helper methods dealing with time and dates.

Comment: Is this object ever going to change? Do any of its properties come from the state or props of one of your components?

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinion-based answer, but in my experience every time you can reduce the complexity of an interface (in this case the props of a component), you're better off.

Six months from now when you need to instantiate another widget component, you won't want to have to ask yourself: "What does this thing take as a prop again? Wait, what's a `timeHelper`? Where else is this used... I'll just copy that."

If the widget component imported the helper directly then that's one less prop you need to worry about.

This isn't true if the component's helper actually *should* be configured. E.g. if `timeHelper`, was a date formatting function  and different instances needed different behaviors.

Note that if the helper is needed in your templates you can create a [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html). For example:

```html
<span>date shared: {{ createdAt | formatDate }}</span>
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking as well: "every time you can reduce the complexity of an interface (in this case the props of a component), you're better off."